# Why does it want to convert from 'Class' to 'Class*'?

Tags: c++

I want to apologize because I know this question has been asked a thousand times before.  I have read all of the similar posts that I can find, but I didn't find my answer.

I am working on the first section of a program that creates a queue of restaurant customers, and pushes the customers onto a stack if they opt in for promotional materials. I have not started coding for the stack.  Right now I'm just trying to get it to load the data file into the queue, which is a linked list, and then print the data.  It won't compile because of this one error.

The error is:

```
error: cannot convert 'Customer' to 'Customer*'
newNode->data = aCustomer
```

Here is my .h file

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H                                                        
#define QUEUE_H                                                        
                                                                       
#include <iostream>                                                    
#include <cstring>                                                     
#include <fstream>                                                     
                                                                       
using namespace std;                                                   
const int CAP = 100;                                                   
class Queue;                                                           
                                                                       
class Customer                                                         
{                                                                      
public:                                                                
        Customer();                                                    
        Customer(Customer& aCustomer);                                 
        Customer(char tempGroupName[], int& tempGroupSize, char tempSpecialSeating[], bool& tempWantsPromo);                                   
        ~Customer(); 
        void openFile(ifstream& infile);                               
        const Customer& operator=(const Customer& aCustomer);          
//      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const Queue& aQueue);
        void setGroupName(char *tempGroupName);
        void setGroupSize(int &tempGroupSize);
        void setSpecialSeating(char * tempSpecialSeating);             
        void setWantsPromo(bool &tempWantsPromo);
private:
        char * groupName;                                              
        int groupSize;
        char * specialSeating;                                         
        bool wantsPromo;
};      

class Queue                                                            
{
public:                                                    
        Queue();                                                       
        Queue(Queue& aQueue);
        ~Queue();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const Queue& aQueue);
        void loadQueue(ifstream& infile, Customer& aCustomer);
        void addCustomer(Customer& aCustomer);
        void enqueue(Queue& aQueue);
        void dequeue(Queue& aQueue);
        void peek();
        void displayList();
        void displayWait();
        void isEmpty();
        bool promotions();
        void mostRecent();

private:
        struct Node
        {
                Node(Customer& aCustomer)
                {
                        data = new Customer(aCustomer);
                //      Node * next = nullptr;
                //      Node * prev = nullptr;
                }
                Customer * data;
                Node *prev, *next;

        };
        Node * head;
        Node * tail;
        int lineSize;
};
#endif
```

And here is the function where I'm getting the error on the second line "newNode->data = aCustomer"

```
void Queue::addCustomer(Customer& aCustomer)                           
{       
        Node* newNode;
        newNode->data = aCustomer;                                     
        newNode->next = nullptr;                                       
        
        if(head == nullptr)                                            
        {       
                head = newNode;                                        
                tail = newNode;                                        
        }
        else                                                           
        {       
                tail->next = newNode;                                  
                tail = newNode;                                        
        }                                                              
}
```

My understanding is that the compiler was expecting a pointer? But I don't get it.

Why would it think it should be a pointer? Is it because newNode is a pointer?

I tried not to post a wall of code, but I'm happy to post more if needed.

Comment: For a start, reduce your code to a [mcve], which is both required for such questions here and it also helps you understand the problem. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Why should compiler *not* expect a pointer? `data` in `Node` is of type `Customer*`, which is a pointer.

Comment: `Node:data` is of type `Customer *` is `customer` in `void Queue::addCustomer(Customer& aCustomer)` a `Customer *`?

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be reduced to this:

```cpp
class Customer{};

int main()
{
    Customer cust;
    Customer &cust_ref = cust;
//  Customer *cust_ptr = cust_ref;   // Error These are different types
    Customer *cust_ptr = &cust_ref;  // This is ok
}
```

In your code newNode->data is a `customer *` (pointer) and aCustomer is a `Customer &` (reference). To make that assignment work change it to:

```
newNode->data = &aCustomer; // Take the address with &
```

Comment: Thank you code_fodder, I figured it was something simple like that.  It compiles now! :) How do I mark it as solved?

Comment: @Jill you can click the `tick` next to the answer to mark as solved and the up arrow next to the question if you liked the answer (or the down arrow if you did not) or neither!

Comment: FYI Op cannot upvote or downvote as they don't have at least 15 rep (for upvote), though they can mark the answer as accepted